# Controlling chart type in xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

How does one control the type of chart when making charts in Excel using **xlwings** from python?

I don't see anything in the current documentation: http://docs.xlwings.org/chart.html

as in the example given in the quickstart to xlwings:

```
from xlwings import Workbook, Range, Chart
wb = Workbook()  # Creates a connection with a new workbook
Range('A1').value = ['Foo 1', 'Foo 2', 'Foo 3', 'Foo 4']
Range('A2').value = [10, 20, 30, 40]
chart = Chart().add()
chart.set_source_data(Range('A1').table)
```

Then I haven't found a way of controlling what kind of chart is added to the Excel workbook ...

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the basic functionalities that is still missing for charts, as noted in the docs. It's logged [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/1#issuecomment-39536876), so it'll hopefully make it into the next version.

However, all is not lost: You can control the chart by accessing the underlying COM object like so (following up on your code above):

```
chart.xl_chart.Chart.ChartType = -4102
```

You'll have to look up the value for the specific chart type you want from the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838409%28v=office.15%29.aspx). So not very pretty but it should work until it's implemented in xlwings.

Comment: This has now been added to v0.1.1, see Release Notes here: http://docs.xlwings.org/whatsnew.html#v0-1-1-june-27-2014

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use win32com? With that you get the full Excel Object model so you can do anything you could if you were using VBA.

I found a small code sample for adding a chart using win32com here:
http://techlinksandstuff.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/using-python-to-plot-in-excel.html

The object model is documented on MSDN, or it's exactly the same as what you'd do in VBA if you're familiar with that.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Or you could write the code yourself, and submit a patch. If you can conjure up the Chart through the Excel interface, you can figure out what objects and maneuvers are needed using the Macro Recorder for VBA.

Translating that very specific generated VBA code into general purpose Python would take some work, but you would have the Excel VB Editor's Object Browser, IntelliSense, and Help files to guide you. The coding style for the Python is pretty straightforward, once you follow the use of decorators to make things manageable.

It could be fun. If not for you, then for someone who reads this question.

Comment: The question was about adding support to http://xlwings.org, not about general purpose Python.